# Getting .gpx into mapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, gpx

Is there a way to get .gpx files pulled from my Garmin GPS60 with MapSource into MapInfo 12?

I know I can grab the data as .txt and fiddle with it in Excel first, just wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

I use a GPX2Tab utility that you can download here -:

http://www.wap3.com/download/gpx2tab.zip

Answer (score 0):

I use QGIS - which deals really well with GPX files - to convert back and forth from/to MapInfo. Often I don't even bother putting the file into MapInfo because what I want to do is just as easy in QGIS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Encom Discover, go to Import and Export > Vector Export and pick the desired table from the list and then choose ‘GPS eXchange (*.gpx)’ and click OK.

Select ‘Reproject coordinates’ and specify a new projection (if desired)

Click Export.